# Document Image response in Spring REST Docs

Tags: spring, spring-restdocs

I have a REST endpoint that generates random images.  I'm using Spring REST Docs, but the Response is all garbled in the http-response.adoc file.  Is there an easy way for Mock MVC and REST Docs to store the file somewhere so my .adoc files can reference it?

Comment: Are you trying to get the image to appear in your documentation as part of the HTTP response snippet or are you looking to include the image in your documentation in place of the HTTP response snippet?

Comment: I'd like to be able to include the image as part of the HTTP response snippet.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand how you expect that to work. Can you expand your question a bit to describe in detail what you'd like the resulting documentation to look like? Please note that the HTTP response snippet contains the actual HTTP response (its headers and body). The response body isn't an image, it's binary data that can be turned into an image.

Comment: When I run my document generating mock MVC tests, I get .adoc files as output.  For example, get-person/1/http-response.adoc .  This file uses the source code syntax.  I'm suggesting that the output for an image would either be the image bytes named http-response.png,  or a file named http-response.adoc with an image:: reference.  That reference would point to the image file generated by the mockMvc test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not the perfect but working solution:

```
class ImageSnippet implements Snippet {

    private final String filePath;

    public ImageSnippet(String filePath) {
        this.filePath = filePath;
    }

    @Override
    public void document(Operation operation) throws IOException {
        byte[] picture = operation.getResponse().getContent();

        Path path = Paths.get(filePath);
        Files.deleteIfExists(path);
        Files.createDirectories(path.getParent());
        Files.createFile(path);

        try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(path.toFile())) {
            fos.write(picture);
        }
    }
}
```

And usage in MockMvc test (image folder path is important):

```
    mockMvc.perform(get("/my-profile/barcode")
                      .accept(MediaType.IMAGE_PNG))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andDo(document("my-profile/barcode",
                      new ImageSnippet("build/asciidoc/html5/images/barcode.png")));
```

In `.adoc` template:

```
 image::barcode.png[]
```

And here is my `build.gradle` Asciidoctor configuration (`imagesdir` is important):

```
asciidoctor {
    dependsOn test
    backends = ['html5']
    options doctype: 'book'

    attributes = [
            'source-highlighter': 'highlightjs',
            'imagesdir'         : './images',
            'toc'               : 'left',
            'toclevels'         : 3,
            'numbered'          : '',
            'icons'             : 'font',
            'setanchors'        : '',
            'idprefix'          : '',
            'idseparator'       : '-',
            'docinfo1'          : '',
            'safe-mode-unsafe'  : '',
            'allow-uri-read'    : '',
            'snippets'          : snippetsDir,
            linkattrs           : true,
            encoding            : 'utf-8'
    ]

    inputs.dir snippetsDir
    outputDir 'build/asciidoc'
    sourceDir 'src/docs/asciidoc'
    sources {
        include 'index.adoc'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is implement a custom Snippet which saves the resulting response. You can use the RestDocumentationContext attribute of the operation you receive to obtain the output directory.

```
    mockMvc.perform(get("/example"))
            .andDo(document("some-example", operation -> {
                var context = (RestDocumentationContext) operation.getAttributes().get(RestDocumentationContext.class.getName());
                var path = Paths.get(context.getOutputDirectory().getAbsolutePath(), operation.getName(), "response-file.png");
                Files.createDirectories(path.getParent());
                Files.write(path, operation.getResponse().getContent());
            }));
```

However this will create a .png file in your output directory which generally isn't really useful if you have Asciidoc in a source directory that needs to embed it. So what you can instead do is create an Asciidoc file which contains custom HTML of an image tag with its source being a base64 representation of the response.

```
    mockMvc.perform(get("/example"))
            .andDo(document("some-example", operation -> {
                var context = (RestDocumentationContext) operation.getAttributes().get(RestDocumentationContext.class.getName());
                var path = Paths.get(context.getOutputDirectory().getAbsolutePath(), operation.getName(), "response-file.adoc");
                var outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                outputStream.write("++++\n".getBytes());
                outputStream.write("<img src=\"data:image/png;base64,".getBytes());
                outputStream.write(Base64.getEncoder().encode(operation.getResponse().getContent()));
                outputStream.write("\"/>\n".getBytes());
                outputStream.write("++++\n".getBytes());
                Files.createDirectories(path.getParent());
                Files.write(path, outputStream.toByteArray());
            }));
```

Although a bit more overhead in terms of space, if you use this, you don't need to mess with referencing build files from your sources.

Comment: Not a bad option.  I don't mind referencing build files from my asciidoc though.  I also like the ability to actually see the .png file in the build directory without having to necessarily render via asciidoc.  Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

An alternative way if you don't need/want to show the images in the docs: Use a `ContentModifyingOperationPreprocessor` to replace the bytes with some string that makes it clear to the readers of the documentation that there will be some image bytes in the response.

For example:

```
        mockMvc.perform(get("/api/users/{id}/avatar", user.getId().asString())
                                .with(createCustomerAuth()))
               .andExpect(status().isOk())
               .andDo(document("get-user-avatar-example",
                               null,
                               Preprocessors.preprocessResponse(new ContentModifyingOperationPreprocessor(new ContentModifier() {
                                   @Override
                                   public byte[] modifyContent(byte[] originalContent, MediaType contentType) {
                                       return "<< IMAGE BODY HERE >>".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
                                   }
                               }))));
```

This generates an `adoc` file like this:

```
[source,http,options="nowrap"]
----
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: image/png
Content-Length: 15
Cache-Control: max-age=3600

<< IMAGE BODY HERE >>
----
```